# jitsi virtual background feature 'tflite.js' file not working

Tags: reactjs, webassembly, jitsi

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/tree/master/react/features/stream-effects/virtual-background/vendor/tflite

After downloading the jitsi open source react project, I ran it like this.

1. npm install
2. yarn start
   [image]

I analyzed the source code, and it was implementing the virtual background using the file below.

```
import createTFLiteModule from './vendor/tflite/tflite';
import createTFLiteSIMDModule from './vendor/tflite/tflite-simd';
```

[image]

However, when I moved it to another react project and ran it, the following error occurred.

```
./src/features/stream-effects/virtual-background/vendor/tflite/tflite.js
  Line 9:   'read' is not defined                     no-undef
  Line 9:   'readbuffer' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 9:   'read' is not defined                     no-undef
  Line 9:   'scriptArgs' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 9:   'quit' is not defined                     no-undef
  Line 9:   Unexpected use of 'print'                 no-restricted-globals
  Line 9:   Unexpected use of 'print'                 no-restricted-globals
  Line 9:   'printErr' is not defined                 no-undef
  Line 9:   Unexpected use of 'print'                 no-restricted-globals
  Line 9:   Unexpected use of 'self'                  no-restricted-globals
  Line 9:  'dateNow' is not defined                  no-undef
  Line 18:    'define' is not defined                   no-undef
  Line 19:     Expected imports instead of AMD define()  import/no-amd
  Line 19:     'define' is not defined                   no-undef
```

[image]

[Questions]
The tflite.js file that has already been created generates the above error.
If I want to use the 'already created tflite.js file' in the jitsi open source in another project, do I need a separate setting?

[Other methods tried]
I couldn't use the tflite.js file I was looking at in open source, so I checked another method.
I was confused whether I should use the wasm file directly, I referred to the official document below, but this also gave me an error.

- Documents on using wasm that I referenced:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.
```

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rslHg.png

Please check tflite.js file. Problem is with environment.

Comment: I imported the tflite.js file like this.
But I don’t know if this is the right way.

1) Insert 4 files in public folder.
ex) https://github.com/Volcomix/virtual-background/tree/main/public/tflite

2) Call js file in index.html file in public folder
ex) https://github.com/Volcomix/virtual-background/blob/main/public/index.html

3) Use like a global variable
ex)const createTFLiteModule = window.createTFLiteModule;
ex)const createTFLiteSIMDModule = window.createTFLiteSIMDModule;

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/react/features/stream-effects/virtual-background/index.js

Comment: There are 4 environments in the tflite.js file. 1. ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB, 2.ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER, 3. ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE, 4.ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL.... In your case it is picking up shell environment and not the able to get libraries or dependencies what's required to run with shell environment.  Please check web assembly supported in your browser if yes, you have enabled on your browser. Reference link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly